# How to set indicator value equal to TRUE if multiple column values are NULL?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to set the values in my indicator column 'match' equal to TRUE if the values in the 'State_db', 'Year_db', and 'Type_db' columns are all NULL. Another condition my code applies is checking if 'State_j'== 'State_db', 'Year_j'=='Year_db', and 'Type_j'=='Type_db', but this works just fine.

This is what my dataframe looks like:

```
State_j Year_j  Type_j  File                  State_db   Year_db     Type_db                    
NY      2020    ICF     2020_ICF_R2_NY_01     NaN        NaN         NaN
WA      2020    OP      2020_OP_R10_WA_01     WA         2020.0      IP
WA      2020    IP      2020_IP_R10_WA_01     WA         2020.0      IP
NJ      2021    ICF     2021_ICF_R2_NJ_01     NY         2022.0      ICF
CA      2021    PRTF    2021_PRTF_R2_CA_02    CA         2021.0      NaN
MI      2021    PRTF    2021_PRTF_R2_MI_02    NaN        2021.0      NaN

State_match     Year_match     Type_match
False           False          False
True            True           False
True            True           True
False           False          True
True            True           False
False           True           False
```

This is what I want the final dataframe to look like:

```
State   Year  Type  File                 State_db   Year_db    Type_db 
NY      2020  ICF   2020_ICF_R2_NY_01    NaN        NaN        NaN   
WA      2020  OP    2020_OP_R10_WA_01    WA         2020.0     IP       
WA      2020  IP    2020_IP_R10_WA_01    WA         2020.0     IP       
NJ      2021  ICF   2021_ICF_R2_NJ_01    NY         2022.0     ICF      
CA      2021  PRTF  2021_PRTF_R2_CA_02   CA         2021.0     NaN      
MI      2021  PRTF  2021_PRTF_R2_MI_02   NaN        2021.0     NaN

State_match     Year_match     Type_match     match
False           False          False          True
True            True           False          False
True            True           True           True
False           False          True           False
True            True           False          False
False           True           False          False
```

This is my code:

```
# Create columns to check for matching state, year, and service type cols
def assemble_report(df):  
    matches_cols = []
    for col in ['State', 'Year', 'Type']:
        df[f'{col}_match'] = (df[f'{col}_j'] == df[f'{col}_db'])  
        matches_cols.append(f'{col}_match') 

    # Create indicator column for whether all keys matched
    df['match'] = df[matches_cols].all(axis='columns')
    df.loc[(df[f'{col}_db'].isnull().all(axis='columns')), 'match'] = "True"
    
    return matches_cols
```

Most of the code works as properly, but it's this bit that's giving me issues:

```
df.loc[(df[f'{col}_db'].isnull().all(axis='columns')), 'match'] = "True"
```

Basically, I want the indicator value 'match' to equal TRUE if the values in 'State_db', 'Year_db', and 'Type_db' are all NULL.

I'm fairly certain the piece of code above is triggering this error:

```
ValueError: No axis named columns for object type <class 'type'>
```

What I'm doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_null(x):
    return x['State_db'] == 'NaN' and x['Year_db'] == 'NaN' and x['Type_db'] == 'NaN'


def check_cond(x):
    return x['State_j'] == x['State_db'] and float(x['Year_j']) == float(x['Year_db']) and x['Type_j'] == x['Type_db']


df['match'] = df.apply(lambda x: check_null(x) or check_cond(x), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    State_j     Year_j  Type_j  File                State_db    Year_db     Type_db     match
1   NY          2020    ICF     2020_ICF_R2_NY_01   NaN         NaN     NaN     True
2   WA          2020    OP      2020_OP_R10_WA_01   WA          2020.0  IP      False
3   WA          2020    IP      2020_IP_R10_WA_01   WA          2020.0  IP      True
4   NJ          2021    ICF     2021_ICF_R2_NJ_01   NY          2022.0  ICF     False
5   CA          2021    PRTF    2021_PRTF_R2_CA_02  CA          2021.0  NaN     False
6   MI          2021    PRTF    2021_PRTF_R2_MI_02  NaN         2021.0  NaN     False
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make a new dataframe to all `True`, `False` entries by `df2 = df.isnull().any().any()`. If the original entry is null, it is `True`, else `False`.

Then define `df['match'][i] = df2['State_db'][i] and df2['Year_db'][i] and df2['Type_db'][i]`, using logical `and` operator for `true` and `false`, for `i` in `0` to max row entries.

Answer (score 0):

Another method, you can use lambda + pd.isnull for that

```
df['match']=df.apply(lambda x: pd.isnull(x['State_db']) and pd.isnull(x['Year_db']) and pd.isnull(x['Type_db']), axis=1)
```